# Images are SOMETIMES there 

Tags: blogger

Okay, I admit that the code is a right mess but I am an old dog who's new at this!
It's a Blogger CSS template that I have been hacking around (and using with Blogger)
and it now does what I want it to do ... sometimes.
However, there is a pattern to the misbehaviour:
First load: it's usually all there and looks good.
Refresh, reload or F5 and often the top image disappears, or something else goes wonky.
Retype the address in the address bar and it usually comes right.
Happens in IE and in Firefox.
If I should clean it up before asking, just say so and expect another post in about a week..
Otherwise, please take a peek:
[www.belindascott.be](http://www.belindascott.be)

Comment: By "top image”, do you mean http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Zuzii37VUO4/Rvc3c3VpGgI/AAAAAAAACNY/Tsy9wsTkn24/s1600/int_l.gif ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Synetech - I should have been more specific. The image that fails to appear from time to time is the main site header logo - this one: <a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_6g7cFLMidBs/SmGSVGrl6YI/AAAAAAAABe4/KrRcfjDXl_w/s1600/Belinda5.jpg"</a>

Comment: Seems I can't edit that post. This is the image:
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_6g7cFLMidBs/SmGSVGrl6YI/AAAAAAAABe4/KrRcfjDXl_w/s1600/Belinda5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems I have sorted it out. The page has eight tiny "corner" images each 18x18px. When the browser couldn't "find them (fast enough?)" it would leave a placemark and sometimes wouldn't display the main title image. I have now uploaded all the images into one Blogger draft post and I reference them from there. Same images, now all in "one place" ... no more problems.

Comment: 2013 and we still have these issues with Blogger. I've got the same situation, but in my case, the custom CSS I inserted for a block don't loads. And this happens randomly, sometimes at first page load, or on refresh... And I can't find a way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known blogger bug

Go to Dashboard, select Template from the pulldown menu, and Edit HTML. Then scroll down until you see the following lines at the bottom of the template:

```
 <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      setTimeout(function() {
        blogger.ui().configure().view();
      }, 0);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Change the timeout value from 0 to 1000:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      setTimeout(function() {
        blogger.ui().configure().view();
      }, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Credit for this trick](http://www.2globalnomads.info/2013/06/blogger-dynamic-views-css-fail-bug-custom-reload.html)